# How to determine a daily spending budget for Google Ads EXCLUDING weekends?

Tags: google-ads

Lets say I have a budget of $100.00 and if I use google's formula to determine daily spend (monthly spend / 30.4) I get roughly $3.30 a day to spend.

But I don't want these ads to run on the weekend. Which changes the formula I would assume..

Would I subtract the weekends out of 30.4 then calculate a daily spend which would allow me to spend more per day? or would Google only work from the 30.4 number and ignores the weekend exclusion?

Comment: Shout outs to the absolute moron who downvoted a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

They will not honor weekend exclusions for a monthly budget. If you exclude weekends and adjust budget it will still calculate your payment threshold with the formula: `Monthly Budget / 30.4`. Say you have 500 monthly spend for Google Ads, and you set daily spending at 16.40 a day, you will on average spend around ~500 give or take.

If you exclude weekends say you know your ads will run 24 days this month, not 30.4.  If your budget using `Monthly budget / 24` you will get $20.80 daily budget but google will apply that to a 30.4-month schedule. which means you actually just set a monthly budget of ~630.00 to give or take. I have a real working example which confirms this.